# Ubuntu not working after formatting windows partition

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, partitioning, format

When I formated my partition with Windows 8.1 on it and nothing else and restarted the PC the top bar disappeared, the menu bar disappeared, I am unable to start the terminal, the windows don't have any border, nor top bar with close, minimize, maximize, etc. But grub works and when I am in the login window the top var is there. I tried with repair packages, but it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to reinstall Unity, may help:

> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
>
> sudo apt-get install unity
>
> sudo shutdown -r now